# how to prove that there is a zero when IVT does not work?

Tags: calculus

for cases like $x^2$ the zero is to an even power, meaning that IVT does not work.

How to prove that there is a zero or not over $[a,b]$? Note: $f(x)$ is differentiable over $(a,b)$ and continuous at the $a$ and $b$.

Comment: There's not really a general procedure, other than the one that comes from logic: to prove $\exists x$ such that $f(x)=0$, you have to find the appropriate $x$ using whatever tools of logic and/or mathematical skill and/or imagination that are available to you, and using that value of $x$ you have to prove $f(x)=0$. The example $f(x)=x^2$ is pretty easy. We teach methods for quadratic polynomials which you no doubt know, I imagine. For quartic/sextic/octic/... polynomials, it's trickier...

Comment: For polynomials in general, you might like to learn Descartes' Rule of Signs. It's not foolproof, but when it works its great.

Comment: You can find the minimum and maximum of $f$: if one of them is $0$ you are done. If both have the same sign there is no root, and if the minimum is negative and the maximum is positive the IVT tells you there is a zero.

Comment: @LeeMosher: there are many well-known general procedures for isolating the roots of polynomial. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials

Comment: Are you interested in polynomial functions or a more general functions?

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square and look for maximum or minimum point may be helpful. 
For example $$ f(x) = x^2-6x+9 = (x-3)^2$$  which has a double root at $x=3$

For functions such as $$ f(x) = x^2-6x+10 = 1+(x-3)^2$$ the process shows that there is no real zeros for this function because the minimum value is 1 which is attained at x=3.

Answer (score 0):

The Intermediate Value Theorem says that a continuous function that attains negative and positive values also has (at least one) zero.

For $x^2$ the 'zero is to an even power' but this is not why the IVT does not work. There are many functions where the zeros are not being found through IVT, such as

$f(x)=1-\cos(x)$

$g(x)=x^2e^x$

$h(x)=\sqrt{x}$

In those cases, the IVT cannot be applied because the absolute minimum (or maximum) **is** the zero itself, so we find the zero on the way to attempting to apply IVT.

My procedure is to find the absolute minimum and maximum of the function on $[a,b]$ by examining critical points and endpoints.

(1) If the absolute minimum is negative and the absolute maximum is positive, then we are guaranteed a zero by the IVT. If the min/max occur at interior points instead of endpoints, we are even guaranteed two zeros: one on the way down and another on the way up.

(2) If the absolute minimum is zero, then we've actually found our zero, case closed. (Similarly if the absolute max is zero then this is our zero.)

(3) Finally, if the absolute minimum and absolute maximum are both the same sign, then by definition the function has been unable to make it to zero, and there is no zero.